# Не запускается Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Не запускается python 3.5.0.

ОС Windows, возникает следующая ошибка:

> Python.exe - System Error
>
> The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is
>   missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this
>   problem.

Подскажите, что мне делать с этим.

Comment: Пробовали переустановить python?

Comment: Попробуйте [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) установить.

Comment: С какой целью(зачем)?

Comment: @Dmitry, с той целью, что указанная библиотека (api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll) относится к Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: попробуй переустановить пакет python полностью

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file/33274879#33274879) [@alireza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3128774) (в одной из редакций) с английского stackoverflow (не относится напрямую к Python 3.5, но относится к `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`).

> ### api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing when open office file
>
> Программа не запускается из-за того, что на компьютере отсутствует
>   библиотека `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`. Проблема в том, что не
>   установлено обновление KB2999226 (Universal CRT), которое является
>   частью Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.
>
> Первое решение - установить все доступные обновления (комментарий: что
>   не для всех допустимо, например из-за пиратских Windows или
>   возникающих предложений обновиться до Win10): Пуск - Панель управления
>   - Обновление Windows, проверить наличие обновлений, установить все доступные обновления. После установки обновлений перезапустить
>   компьютер. Повторять пока не останется не установленных обновлений.
>
> Можно скачать Visual C++ Redistributable отдельно:
>
> Для Windows 64-bit:
>   http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe
>
> Для Windows 32-bit:
>   http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe
>
> Запустите `vcredist_x64.exe` (64-bit) или `vcredist_x86.exe` (32-bit)
>   выберите сначала удаление, после этого установите заново.

Answer (score 1):

Перевожу (если нужно) в тексту ошибки написано:

`Программа не может запуститься потому-что api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`(windows библиотека) `отсутствует на вашем компьютере. Попробуйте переустановить программу чтобы исправить эту проблему`

Answer (score 0):

Требуется переустановить Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, т.к. отсутствует одна из Windows библиотек.