# Ошибка - LoadLibrary: Не найден указанный модуль - при запуске exe на другом ПК

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Собрал Pyqt5 Проект в Exe. Проверил, у меня открывается, проверил на другом компе на котором не стоит Python, открывается. Стоит отметить что в обоих случаях стоит Windows 10 (X64). Принёс программу в Универ там установлена Windows 7(скорее всего x32). 
Выдало следующие ошибки:

> Error loading Python DLL 'E:\main\python37.dll
>   LoadLibrary: Не найден указанный модуль.

Он есть, на флешке, лежит в папке main, но почему то не хочет, грузиться.
А так же высветилась ошибка:

> Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll. Попробуйте переустановить программу

Почему так произошло?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Не запускается Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540821/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-python) - второй вопрос(точно не уверен, но вроде подойдёт).
http://volodichev.com/pyexe/ - первый вопрос(+много другой инфы по .exe из .py).
Надеюсь этого достаточно)